# How do I change the default assignment of field in ASP.NET TreeView control?

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have this code setup currently:

```
TreeView tree;
TreeNodeBinding treeNodeBinding = new TreeNodeBinding();
treeNodeBinding.TextField = "Name";
treeNodeBinding.DataMember = "Address";
treeNodeBinding.ValueField = "Zip";
treeNodeBinding.ToolTipField = "FileName1";

tree.DataBindings.Add(treeNodeBinding);
tree.DataSourceID = "Customers";
tree.DataBind();
```

The datasource (XML) may or may not have an optional attribute called `IsPremium`. If it exists, then I have to add custom business logic that determines what the `treeNodeBinding.ToolTipField` is going to be. The custom business logic will generate a string which needs to be set as the value of the ToolTipField.

How do I override the default behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it. I could use the OnDataBinding function to add custom logic